# I create a Flutter Widget but it does not display on AVD

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build an App, in this I have an issue with a Widget, I could not find where I am wrong. Could you help me for this. The Countries should place at the bottom of AVD screen.

What should I do for diplay countries on AVD manager. I have also debugged but nothing found. I'm beginner coder in Flutter. Sorry for this question but I need help for my course project.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
          ),
        ),
        child: Wrap(
          runSpacing: 20,
          spacing: 20,
          children: <Widget>[
            InfoCard(
              title: 'Confirmed Cases',
              iconColor: Color(0xFFFF2D55),
              effectedNum: 75,
            ),
            InfoCard(
              title: 'Total Deaths',
              iconColor: Color(0xFFFF8C00),
              effectedNum: 1062,
            ),
            InfoCard(
              title: 'Total Recovered',
              iconColor: Color(0xFF50E3C2),
              effectedNum: 689,
            ),
            InfoCard(
              title: 'New Cases',
              iconColor: Color(0xFF5856D6),
              effectedNum: 52,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


class Countries extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 100, right: 20, bottom: 200),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                const ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('America'),
                  subtitle: Text('Confirmed Cases: 23.8 Mn'
                      'Confirmed Death: 396K'),
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wGGW.png)

Comment: What exactly you want brother?

Comment: There are many issues with your code. Try removing scaffold on the Countries widget and use a Column to wrap Container in body of HomeScreen and place Countries below it. Posted a general overview in my answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: Column(children:[Container(child:Wrap(children: ...)),Countries(),]),
    );
  }
}

class Countries extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(...);//remove Scaffold
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do your said, I get this display, https://prnt.sc/x1sjzq but I dont want to do like that. You understand wrong the issue

Comment: No you misunderstood me. I have made changes to the code. Column should be a parent of your old code and Countries().